# MongoDB groupby with regex

Tags: mongodb

Say, there are two documents like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56554226da00060cd7dd7db5"),
    "SegmentName" : "LTV90-Sub Prime",
    "Segment_Behaviour" : "LTV90",
    "Segment_Risk" : "Sub Prime",
    "CohortMonthYear" : "01-01-2010",
    "CohortQuarterYear" : "Q1 2010",
    "DriverName" : "Active rate",
    "MonthsOnBooks" : 2,
    "DriverValue" : 0.9315880000000000,
    "Accounts" : 5400,
    "PortfolioId" : ObjectId("56554225c95a8a161c262853")
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56554226da00060cd7dd7db4"),
    "SegmentName" : "LTV140-Near Prime",
    "Segment_Behaviour" : "LTV140",
    "Segment_Risk" : "Near Prime",
    "CohortMonthYear" : "01-01-2010",
    "CohortQuarterYear" : "Q1 2010",
    "DriverName" : "Active rate",
    "MonthsOnBooks" : 1,
    "DriverValue" : 0.9800000000000000,
    "Accounts" : 5400,
    "PortfolioId" : ObjectId("56554225c95a8a161c262853")
}
```

I need to do aggregation and pull out all the field names and values when the regex "Segment_" matches.

Currently I am matching the documents with PortfolioId and then aggregating the SegmentName, Accounts with the below query.

```
db.PortfolioData.aggregate([{$match:{PortfolioId:ObjectId("56554225c95a8a161c262853")}},
            {"$group": {
                "_id": {"PortfolioId": "$PortfolioId", "SegmentName": "$SegmentName", "Accounts": "$Accounts"},}}]
            );
```

Now, I need to also take the field name and value when the regex matches "Segment_".

**Current Result**

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "PortfolioId" : ObjectId("56554225c95a8a161c262853"),
                "SegmentName" : "LTV90-Sub Prime",
                "Accounts" : 5400
            }
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "PortfolioId" : ObjectId("56554225c95a8a161c262853"),
                "SegmentName" : "LTV140-Near Prime",
                "Accounts" : 24718
            }
        }, 
   ],
    "ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}
```

**Expected Result:**

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "_id": {
                "PortfolioId": ObjectId("56554225c95a8a161c262853"),
                "SegmentName": "LTV90-Sub Prime",
                "Segment_Behaviour": "LTV90",
                "Segment_Risk": "Sub Prime",
                "Accounts": 7675
            }
        },
        {
            "_id": {
                "PortfolioId": ObjectId("56554225c95a8a161c262853"),
                "SegmentName": "LTV140-Near Prime",
                "Segment_Behaviour": "LTV140",
                "Segment_Risk": "Near Prime",
                "Accounts": 24718
            }
        },
    ],
    "ok": 1.0000000000000000
}
```

Thanks

Comment: No really clear what you are trying to do here other than splitting a string by the hyphen `"-"`. You cannot do that in the aggregation framework as there is no operation to support that. There is only [`$substr`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/) but that would require fixed lengths, and in your sample the characters to the hyphen are not of fixed length, but variable. You could use mapReduce with JavaScript `.split()`, but it is not really clear what you are trying to achieve as this is just distinct data in return. Probably best to do in the client.

Comment: Why don't you include Segment_Behaviour and Segment_Risk in the group stage. If you are unsure about the number of fields in starting with Segment_ then its better to redefine the schema. Have an object called Segment and put Behaviour , Risk and other segment fields inside it. Then you need to group by Segment alone.

Comment: The problem is I don't know what comes after Segment_. It can be Behaviour or something else. Is there any way I can find the fields which starts with Segment_?

Comment: In that case why cant you  restructure your collection such that all Segment related attributes comes under one key?